# Error 1064: Syntax Error MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error, server

I'm doing sentences for an exercise and MySQL keeps bringing me that error in this sentence.

```
delete centros where cod_centros not in(select cod_centro from personal);
```

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CENTROS (
 COD_CENTRO   integer NOT NULL,
 TIPO_CENTRO  CHAR(1),
 NOMBRE VARCHAR(30),
 DIRECCION VARCHAR(26),
 TELEFONO VARCHAR(10),
 NUM_PLAZAS integer,
 primary key (cod_centro)
 );

CREATE TABLE PERSONAL (
 COD_CENTRO   integer NOT NULL,
 DNI integer,
 APELLIDOS VARCHAR(30),
 FUNCION VARCHAR(15),
 SALARIO integer,
 primary key (cod_centro,dni),
 foreign key (cod_centro) references Centros(cod_centro)
);
```

And here are the inserts:

```
INSERT INTO CENTROS VALUES (10,'S','IES El Quijote', 
'Avda. Los Molinos 25', '965-887654',538);
INSERT INTO CENTROS VALUES (15,'P','CP Los Danzantes', 'C/Las Musas s/n',
'985-112322',250);
INSERT INTO CENTROS VALUES (22,'S', 'IES Planeta Tierra', 'C/Mina 45',
'925-443400',300);
INSERT INTO CENTROS VALUES (45,'P', 'CP Manuel Hidalgo', 'C/Granada 5',
'926-202310',220);
INSERT INTO CENTROS VALUES (50,'S', 'IES Antoñete', 'C/Los Toreros 21',
'989-406090',310);


INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (10,1112345,'Martínez Salas, Fernando',
'PROFESOR', 220000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (10,4123005,'Bueno Zarco, Elisa', 
'PROFESOR', 220000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (10,4122025,'Montes García, M.Pilar', 
'PROFESOR', 220000);

INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (15,1112345,'Rivera Silvestre, Ana',
'PROFESOR', 205000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (15,9800990, 'Ramos Ruiz, Luis',
'PROFESOR', 205000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (15,8660990, 'De Lucas Fdez, M.Angel',
'PROFESOR', 205000);

INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (22,7650000, 'Ruiz Lafuente, Manuel',
'PROFESOR', 220000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (45,43526789, 'Serrano Laguía, María',
'PROFESOR', 205000);


INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (10,4480099,'Ruano Cerezo, Manuel',
'ADMINISTRATIVO', 180000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (15,1002345,'Albarrán Serrano, Alicia',
'ADMINISTRATIVO', 180000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (15,7002660,'Muñoz Rey, Felicia',
'ADMINISTRATIVO', 180000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (22,5502678,'Marín Marín, Pedro',
'ADMINISTRATIVO', 180000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (22,6600980, 'Peinado Gil, Elena',
'CONSERJE', 175000);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (45,4163222, 'Sarro Molina, Carmen',
'CONSERJE', 175000);
```

I don't know what to do, I think the syntax of the select is fine but keeps bringing the error so I was thinking that maybe it's a bug from mysql workbench as always but I dunno what to do!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `from` keyword, which indicates which table you're deleting from.

Correct solution:

```
delete from centros where cod_centros not in (select cod_centro from personal);
```

Here's the original, complete, single-table syntax:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Reference: [MySQL's DELETE Syntax Single-table syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, my god I dunno how I couldn't see that, bad day I guess. Thanks again! Have a nice day!

Comment: @MikeZyxt You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as the accepted one by checking the check-mark -- when it unlocks :)

Answer (score 0):

Centros is the name of the table so you want to say "Delete FROM Centros where..."